# How can I change my login account, yet still keep my rep and privileges?

Tags: support, login

I use OpenID to log into Stackoverflow. I want to drop my OpenID and use my Google account to login, keeping my rep and privileges. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your account (click your name at the top of any page), click **add openid** and add your Google account. That should be it.

Comment: @biju: No problem.

Comment: I can't find any option to add openid. I'm using Google account and want to add OpenID login(different email). Please advise. Thanks.